# Creating interactive pivot table in unix server like windows excel

Tags: excel, unix, sas, pivot, interactive

I work in sas in unix server and create my summarized table (~1.5GB) there. Then I have to download it to windows to create pivot table out of it. Unfortunately the download speed from server to desktop is very slow, so it takes a lot of time to get downloaded(~20-30 minutes).

Is there any software (preferably free) which can directly create interactive pivot tables in unix server like we create in windows excel?

Comment: One use of a pivot table is to perform summarization of categorical data, much like `Proc TABULATE`.  What does the 'unix side' summarization table look like ? How many rows ? Are there any very wide character columns ? I doubt Excel is going to like 1.5GB of data regardless of where the workbook is made.  Do you have SAS add in for Office ?

Comment: I'll second the assumption that you're not getting 1.5GB into Excel. You can likely connect to it using other tools but not directly. What type of interactivity do you need? How many rows do you have? There's a few options available to create interactive data, either using SAS or other tools.

Comment: https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/tableeditor/index.html This may be another option as well.